# Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined at admin.firestore.collection.doc.get.then.doc

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I created this Firebase Functions(onCreate user trigger) to return the new user data and create a realtime notification.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)

const createNotification = (notification => {
    return admin.firestore().collection('notifications')
        .add(notification)
        .then(doc => console.log('notification added', doc))
})

exports.userJoined = functions.auth.user().onCreate(user => {
    return admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(user.uid).get().then(doc => {
        const newUser = doc.data()
        const notification = {
            content: 'Joined the app',
            user: `${newUser.firstName} ${newUser.lastName}`,
            time: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
        }

        return createNotification(notification)
    })
})
```

The first time I use `firebase deploy` and create a new user, the trigger works perfectly. But the second and the subsequent attempts the `Firebase Function logs` returns me the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined
    at admin.firestore.collection.doc.get.then.doc (/user_code/index.js:28:29)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

Comment: The error happens if there is no document under `users` for the user that was just created.

Comment: Yes, this is clear to me, however whenever I use 'firebase deploy' and create a new user, the function does not return error, but if I create more than 1 user, the second and subsequent ones that will be created will give this error. So, I need to  'firebase deploy' every time I need to create a new user. 
I can not identify the problem, it should give the error on the first try, right?

Comment: How is the user document supposed to get created? Given that you key them on the `uid`, you'll only be able to create it after the user is created. In that case it sounds like you have a race condition, where you're experiencing a cold-start after the first deploy, which is apparently long enough for the user document to be created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you key them on the uid, you'll only be able to create it after the user is created. I'm going to assume you do this from the client-side app, right after creating the user.

After you deploy the functions, the next time you run them you're going to have a so-called cold-start, where Cloud Functions spins up a new container for running the new code. This can take some time, and apparently that time is long enough for your client-side app to create the document for the new user.

Repeated calls often won't need to start a new container, in which case your Cloud Function for `functions.auth.user().onCreate` gets triggered before the client-side app has written the user's document.

I recommend turning the function that sends a notification into an HTTPS triggered Cloud Function, and then explicitly calling it from the client-side app after creating the document.

Comment: If they're relying on a user to be added to firestore before sending the notification, could they use `functions.firestore.document("users/{uid}").onCreate...` instead of `functions.auth.user().onCreate` and also avoid race conditions?